# How do we know that the actual universe has no Killing vector fields?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, symmetry, vector-fields

[This article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06473) states the following:

> The infinitude of conserved energies constructed via Noether’s theorem
>   suffers a startling reversal as soon as Special Relativity is
>   superseded by General Relativity. There, **in the generic case and
>   certainly for the actual universe, instead of an infinitude of global
>   time-like Killing vector fields, there are none**.

Is this a basic fact about GR? If so, how does one show that, in general, curved space time has no Killing vector fields?

Comment: Are you asking for some kind of formal proof, or just a conceptual explanation? Conceptually, a Killing vector tells us there is a symmetry. The real universe is lumpy and time-varying in complicated, so obviously it has no such symmetries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local (over scales like the Solar system at least) timelike Killing vectors do exist,  otherwise we could  not formulate and experimentally confirm any conservation low for energy.

What can be said is that the observed expansion of the spatial sections of the universe does not permit a **large scale** timelike Killing vector **orthogonal** to those  spatial sections. This is because the lines representing the stories of galaxies would be simultaneously geodesics and integral lines of the Killing field. A consequence of the Killing symmery would be a stationary 3D geometry  on those spatial sections with respect to the Killing time (or also the local  proper time). Instead, we see an expansion: the spatial distaces between galaxies increases in time. I think there is only the possibility that a large scale **conformal** timelike Killing vector exists, as it seems referring to the cosmic background radiation...

Comment: Where is a good resource (textbook/website) for an introduction to the underlying math here? (E.g., defining "spatial sections", "conformal Killing vectors", and Killing vector calculations)

Comment: You could try Wald's textbook on General Relativity